# How to make a method in a class async using neon

Tags: node.js, rust

I am trying to make the method with a class created with neon and Rust async. but I m not sure how to do so for a class's method.
For example, I would want to have myMethod as an async.

```
use neon::prelude::*;

pub struct SomeClass{
    path: String,
}
declare_types! {

    pub class MyClass for SomeClass {
        init(mut cx) {
            let path = cx.argument::<JsString>(0)?.value(); 
            Ok(Predictor {
                path: path ,
            })
        }

        method myMethod(mut cx) {

            let this = cx.this();
            let guard = cx.lock();

            let test = this.borrow(&guard).path.unwrap();
            
            let vector = vec![1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3,];
            // Iterate over the Rust Vec and map each value in the Vec to the JS array
            let js_array = JsArray::new(&mut cx, vector.len() as u32);
            for (i, obj) in preds.iter().enumerate() {
                let element = cx.number(f64::from(*obj));
                js_array.set(&mut cx, i as u32, element).unwrap();
            }

            Ok(js_array.upcast())
        }

    }
}

// Export the class
register_module!(mut m, {
    // <JsEmployee> tells neon what class we are exporting
    // "Employee" is the name of the export that the class is exported as
    m.export_class::<myClass>("MyClass")?;
    Ok(())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is currently a [todo](https://neon-bindings.com/docs/async/#promises) in neon. But you can create a simple background task and wrap it in `Promise` pretty easily. See documentation for [examples](https://neon-bindings.com/docs/async/#promises).

Rust

```rust
use neon::prelude::*;

struct BackgroundTask;

impl Task for BackgroundTask {
    type Output = i32;
    type Error = String;
    type JsEvent = JsNumber;

    fn perform(&self) -> Result<Self::Output, Self::Error> {
        Ok(17)
    }

    fn complete(self, mut cx: TaskContext, result: Result<Self::Output, Self::Error>) -> JsResult<Self::JsEvent> {
        Ok(cx.number(result.unwrap()))
    }
}

pub fn perform_async_task(mut cx: FunctionContext) -> JsResult<JsUndefined> {
    let f = cx.argument::<JsFunction>(0)?;
    BackgroundTask.schedule(f);
    Ok(cx.undefined())
}

register_module!(mut m, {
    m.export_function("performAsyncTask", perform_async_task)
});
```

JS

```js
// ./lib/index.js
const { performAsyncTask } = require("../native");

// Iterate 10,0000 times in background thread
const promisePerformAsyncTask = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    performAsyncTask((err, res) => {
      let count = 10;
      for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        count++;
      }
      console.log(count, "first sum from background thread");
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: So you're saying it's not possible to do it for methods in classes?